# CSS responsive tables

Tags: html, css

I'm going out of my mind becouse of this. I'm trying to make tables responsive on mobile using only CSS and HTML. Searched google and stackoverflow for hours and still no idea how to grab this problem. Tried different methods and still nothing. Tried div tables and normal.

ok here it goes, i'm trying to make this table > http://postimg.org/image/62upgmozv/ transform via media query 480px into this > http://postimg.org/image/5brtspn5x/

colors and names are important. I need just a suggestion or idea how to solve this. main problem for me is to make div table with separate div for DATE(orange) and then sort it for mobile(see second pic) and then repeat with next date.

Comment: Using bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/ might be a good idea.

Comment: The main thing here is that you are taking a single `name` element (the header cell) and duplicating it, once for each `date` section. CSS cannot do this.

Comment: @Kolink: CSS can do this. OP: can you provide the actual code for your table?

Comment: @GiovanniSilveira Really? CSS can make the same element appear more than once, or clone it? Please do show me this sorcery.

Comment: I will on the answer :) I have done that before

Comment: my code is completly broken after few rebuilds, can you please show me some small demo how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at an example I have made of this: http://www.f1time.com/mobile/

I dont have a code from your table, so I thought I'd share the one I did for that functionality.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
/* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
    display: block; 
}

/* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
thead tr { 
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}

tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

td { 
    /* Behave  like a "row" */
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50%; 
}

td:before { 
    /* Now like a table header */
    position: absolute;
    /* Top/left values mimic padding */
    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    width: 45%; 
    padding-right: 10px; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}


/*
Label the data
*/
td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Current Position"; }
td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Position Change"; }
td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Manager"; }
td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Lap"; }
td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Gap"; }
td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Gap to Front"; }
td:nth-of-type(7):before { content: "Lap Time"; }
td:nth-of-type(8):before { content: "Fastest"; }
td:nth-of-type(9):before { content: "Pits"; }
td:nth-of-type(10):before { content: "Status"; }
}
```

Comment: After asking myself for years now, what are these damn tables usefull for anymore, I finally understand the power of them. + for the answer.

Comment: i dont fully understand that. what about transformig first td(date) to be like a header, then displying header(name) and data under it? then again displying another date and under it, !again name and data

Comment: All you need to be concerned is with the last bit of code. Just change `td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Current Position"; }` content property with the header of your 1st column, and so on... Check the link I posted, and resize your browser (<500px wide), and you will see what happens :)

Comment: @Kolink - No sorcery involved, and it gets the job done... Pure CSS ;-)